# PCRE accumulate multiple occurances of matching group

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I wonder if this is possible. I have the pattern:

`foo:(?<id>\d+)(?::(?<srcid>\d+))*`

Now I match on this specimen:

`asdasdasd {{foo:1381:2:4:7}}`

I get the match:

```
Full match      `foo:1381:2:4:7`
Group `id`      `1381`
Group `srcid`   `7`
```

However, is it possible to get a result such as:

```
Full match      `foo:1381:2:4:7`
Group `id`      `1381`
Group `srcid`   [`2`, `4`, `7`]
```

I need this to work with multiple matches, e.g. `asdasdasd {{foo:1381:2:4:7}} {{foo:1111}}`.

Comment: Not in a single step. You could either match all the `srcid`-numbers and split afterwards or use `\G` and match multiple time, where `id` is only contained in the first match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\G` in your PCRE regex to get multiple matches after end of previous match:

```
(?:{{foo:(?<id>\d+)|(?<!^)\G)(?::(?<srcid>\d+)|}})
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xz4JqR/10)

`\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.

**Sample Code:**

```
$str = 'asdasdasd {{foo:1381:2:4:7}}';
preg_match_all('/(?:foo:(?<id>\d+)|(?<!^)\G):(?<srcid>\d+)/', $str, $m);

print_r($m['srcid']);
echo $m['id'][0]; // 1381
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 7
)
1381
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I should've specified that I need this to work with multiple matches of the whole group. It seems not to work correctly when I try, e.g. `{{foo:1381:2:4:7}}  {{foo:1111}}`. Then the second id is empty. Is that also possible?